# error with creating volatile table in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

```
-drop table r.stray_cust;

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE r.stray_cust
(
CustomerID INTEGER
) 
PRIMARY INDEX ( CustomerID );

INSERT INTO  r.stray_cust
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerid AS customerid
FROM customer c
WHERE c.customerid 
NOT IN (
SELECT a.customerid 
FROM address a );

ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

select * from r.stray_cust;
```

Keep getting an error message - query failed please see history log for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, did you check the history for details?

ON COMMIT is part of the CREATE VOLATILE TABLE, so your query should be:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE r.stray_cust ( CustomerID INTEGER ) PRIMARY INDEX ( CustomerID )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO r.stray_cust
SELECT DISTINCT c.customerid AS customerid 
FROM customer c 
WHERE c.customerid NOT IN ( SELECT a.customerid FROM address a );
```

Or in a single step:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE r.stray_cust AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT c.customerid AS customerid 
  FROM customer c 
  WHERE c.customerid NOT IN ( SELECT a.customerid FROM address a )
)
PRIMARY INDEX ( CustomerID )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

INSERT INTO r.stray_cust
;

Comment: first solution worked perfectly! thanks Dnoeth... but on a side note with volatile tables you can only select one column? i tried adding more columns and received and error message : INSERT FAILED. 3813: The positional assignment list has too many values

Comment: scratch that.. i figured it out. =/